# How to convert to schema.org JSON-LD duration with PHP

Tags: php, schema.org, json-ld

duration in schema.org JSON-LD is in this format "duration": "PT4M5S" that it should be ISO-8601 
but in PHP date('c') should return a string like this 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00 that it seems in a different format

I have time in this format "00:03:06" and I need to get it in schema.org JSON-LD format, not sure if PHP has any way to do it

https://schema.org/duration

Comment: datetime class in php can help you with datetime formats. I guess DATE_ATOM is what you are looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.atom

Comment: it doesn't seem it should have some letters between minutes and seconds PT4M5S it should be 4 minute and 5 seconds not sure what happen if it has hours

Answer (score 1):

To convert a date time string to ISO 8601 duration (PnYnMnDTnHnMnS) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Something like this can be a way.

```
$time = new DateTime('00:03:06');

echo sprintf('PT%dH%dM%dS', $dm->format('H'), (int)$dm->format('i'), (int)$dm->format('s'));
```

> Output: PT0H3M6S

Comment: do you know if it can have hours and if could be H? not sure how it is handle or it will be conveyed in minutes

Comment: there is a class here https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#113415 which can help to convert.